# How to make "show settings" of a reference entity view affect the real field selection

Tags: views, 8

In Drupal 8, I can manage to create an "Entity Reference" view. In the preview area, it shows multiple fields separated by a string separate, just as I configured. For example:

[image: entity reference preview area]

However, in the real form, a selector does not show the expected fields as by configuration, but rather shows only content title:

[image: real selector is not like preview]

I tried clearing cache, but it did not help.
What setting in the view editor should I use to let the live entity selector show fields the same as in the preview?

Comment: Unfortunatelly, this is a known [major bug](https://www.drupal.org/node/2714089) basically entity reference views is broken.